# Selenium IDE click and drag

Tags: selenium, click, drag, selenium-ide

I am using the Selenium IDE extension for testing webpages in FireFox and I was able to find out how to perform almost every command that I need to automate testing for my webpage.

Unfortunately I was not able to find out how to do this through the list of commands that you can manually enter into the queue of Selenium IDE.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this in the Firefox extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dragAndDropToObject` command which locates the target element and drags it to the centre of the destination element.

```
dragAndDropToObject
target: locator of the element to drag
value: locator of the destination element
```

There is also a `dragAndDrop` command which drags the element by specified amount of pixels and drop it.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you might want to use [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/) instead of Selenium IDE.    Also, there are some things that Builder or IDE cannot record, such as iFrame interactions, certain AJAX actions, and also drag and drops.   For those, you need to code them by hand afterwards and get them working.